# USB not working after Boot

Tags: usb

I got a software issue with my RasPi: USB does not work.

When I boot I can access NOOBS (v2.4), mouse and keyboard both work. As soon as Raspian is launched, any USB device does not work anymore.

The issue is on my partition, I tried with an other RasPi, same issue.

I also checked with a different mouse/keyboard/USBStick, no difference.

Someone an idea?

Yes I could just flash a new raspian and everything would be fine again but I would like to safe all the configs, pictures, etc.

Edit: I had the same issue with multiple other RasPis propably after an unattended `apt-get upgrade`. Maybe something popped up, the RasPis "went to sleep" (Mouse and keyboard did not wake them up, maybe the issue already there) and then the power was turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Like most such issues, the answer is simple - just restore from your backup.

If you do not have a backup your only option is a new install.

If you want to recover your data, do a new install on a new SD Card, then  mount the old in a SD Card reader and copy your data.